# Триггер MouseOver накладывается на триггер IsSelected, что делать?

Tags: c#, wpf

Привет всем. Как быть в данной ситуации? Все работает почти как нужно, но не совсем, как только навести мышкой на объект, который isSelected, на него накладывается триггер MouseOver, так сабж: как сделать триггер isSelected главней MouseOver? Пробывал через мультитриггеры, не получилось. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

### Ответ был очень прост, извините за беспокойство.

---

Просто расположил триггер IsMouseOver выше, чем триггер IsSelected.